# Spring 3 MVC @Controller with AOP interceptors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-aop

Anyone knows why apparently it is not possible to use AOP with annotated MVC Controllers? (see [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305938/implement-aop-for-controllers-in-spring-3)).
I have a @Controller that stops working as soon as I add a pointcut to it.
The problem is not that the interceptor is not being called, but rather the @Controller simply stops working (in the log you can see that instead of "Mapped URL path [/xx] onto handler 'Yyy'" you get a "no URL paths identified").

I know there is a mechanism for adding interceptors to controllers via the handlerMapping but my question is specific to AOP interceptors. Aren't annotated controllers just pojos in the Spring container as any other pojo?  What is the difference? Why?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class RestTestImpl implements RestTest {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public @ResponseBody String deleteUsers(String arg) {
        return "Xxxxx";
    }
}
```

In my servlet-Context I have:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.xxx.yyy"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    . . .
</bean>
```

And everything works just great.

But when I add:

```
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* org.xxx.*(..))" id="pc1"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="hibernateInterceptor"  pointcut-ref="pc1" order="2" />
    </aop:config>
```

The controller stops being a controller (no errors, simply it stops binding to the specified URL)!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [Spring MVC Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib):

> **Note**
>   When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying),
>   make sure to consistently **put all your
>   mapping annotations** - such as
>   `@RequestMapping` and `@SessionAttributes`
>   - **on the controller interface** rather than on the implementation class.

Granted, this note is well hidden :-)

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. That's it.  It is generally recommended to put annotations in implementing classes rather than interfaces, but in this case it seems this is the way to go.  Thank you.

Comment: @pakman it is generally **required** to annotate implementing classes, as annotations aren't inherited from interfaces, but the controller annotation logic works on the actual bean at runtime (which may be a proxy), not the static bean class

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd can you examine my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234059/aop-annotation-at-spring-controllers-doesnt-work

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same issue and found out the solution.

Indeed your controller (annotated by @Controller) and your aspects (annotated by @Aspect) should be in the same **Spring context**.

Usually people define their controllers in the **dispatch-servlet.xml** or **xxx-servlet.xml** and their service beans (including the aspects) in the main **applicationContext.xml**. It will not work.

When Spring initializes the MVC context, it will create a proxy for your controller but if your aspects are not in the same context, Spring will not create interceptors for them.

The above ssertion does not depend

- on the way your declare your controllers/aspects (by manual XML declaration or annotation style)
- on the proxying style you choose (JDK proxy or CGLIB)

I've tested all the combinations and they all work as long as the controller & aspects are in the same **Spring context**

Comment: Ty, got the same problem... :)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess without doing some serious digging is because Spring's AOP mechanism that you are using is wrapping the target classes in proxy classes which end up loosing their annotation or the original annotation gets dropped after weaving.

I am sure there is a better answer and I'll expand on mine as I think of a better more clear way to present it.