# Spring MVC 3: AOP on a Controller in MVC context not working

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, aop

I'm trying to advise (for logging purposes) methods that uses @RequestMappging annotations in a Spring Web App with an Aspect. Here is my aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class InboundSpringPerfLoggerAspect extends AbstractInboundPerfLoggerAspect {

@Around(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(requestMapping)" , argNames = "pjp, requestMapping")
public Object doPerfLoggingForOperation(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, final RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {
    return doPerfLogging(pjp, LOGGER_NAME);
}
```

My XML servlet configuration (MVC context) file is this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<!-- Logging aspect for inbound rest calls -->
<bean id="inboundServicePerfLoggerAspect" class="common.logging.aspect.InboundSpringPerfLoggerAspect"/>

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="web.configuration" />
<context:component-scan base-package="web.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="web..service" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean name="xmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

However at start up in DEBUG mode logs from Spring shows same message:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Rejected bean name 'inboundServicePerfLoggerAspect': no URL paths identified
```

And of course controllers classes are not properly advised. They worked fine but no Spring proxy AOP takes place.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862991/spring-3-mvc-controller-with-aop-interceptors