# How to get parameters of request handler in AbstractRequestLoggingFilter or HandlerInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Let's look at this example code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Car> update(@RequestBody Car car) {
    ...
}
```

I have many Controllers and methods like that. I want to log all `RequestBody` parameters (like `Car`). So, I tried to use `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` (afterRequest method) and `HandlerInterceptor`. But I don't see a way, how to get parameters of methods with help of these classes.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Could you please rewrite it in a spirit of [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Spring MVC machinery that convert the request parameters to a `Car` gives the result only to the controller.

There are two ways to do the logging:

- at the request parameter level:
  as a HandlerInterceptor has access to the request, it can read the parameters and log them with the following ServleRequest methods: getParameterNames and getParameterValues, or getParameterMap
- at the service level: if your controller is a thin controller that delegates actual processing to a service class, you can use Spring AOP over the service method with a before advice because it will have access to the `Car` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HandlerMethod.getMethodParameters()` in your `HandlerInterceptor`:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {

    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    MethodParameter[] methodParameters = handlerMethod.getMethodParameters();
    // Inspect & log parameters...

}
```

Comment: could you explain, how to get values from methodParameters?