# Spring AOP Controller Executing twice

Tags: spring, log4j, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

My applicationContext is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="..">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <task:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc">
        <context:include-filter type="aspectj"  expression="com.abc.aspects.LogControllerAspect"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

Have 2 Aspect Java classes, LogControllerAspect (for logging all the calls to Spring Controllers) and LogDAOAspect (for logging all the calls to DB).

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class LogDAOAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Around("execution(* com.*.*DAOImpl.*(..))")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodId = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()+" : "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " : " + ((joinPoint.getArgs()==null||joinPoint.getArgs().length<1)?"":(Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs())));
        Object returnVal = null;
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(methodId);
        try {
            sw.start();
            returnVal= joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
            sw.stop();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error(methodId+"\n"+e);
            throw e;
        }
        logger.debug(methodId + ":" +sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
        return returnVal;
    }
}


@Aspect
public class LogControllerAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Around("execution(* com.*.*Controller.*(..))")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodId = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()+" : "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " : " + ((joinPoint.getArgs()==null||joinPoint.getArgs().length<1)?"":(Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs())));
        Object returnVal = null;
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(methodId);
        try {
            sw.start();
            returnVal= joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
            sw.stop();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error(methodId+"\n"+e);
            throw e;
        }
        logger.debug(methodId + ":" +sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

LogDAOAspect is fine, but LogControllerAspect is logging twice (logAround method is executing twice) when I request some page. I can understand that that aspect is getting proxied twice, but am not sure how to avoid this. Help appreciated.

Comment: are you sure controller methods run once? maybe there is two method calls.

Comment: The method is called only once (I set a breakpoint it hit only once)

Comment: you should check any method under COntroller package `* com.*.*Controller.*(..))`

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake. It was not even a spring related issue!
I had setup log4j as follows !!!???!!!

```
<appender name="AppAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd.HH"/>
    <param name="File" value="logs/logfile.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p : %d{ISO8601} : %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.abc.aspects.LogControllerAspect">
    <priority value="debug"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="AppAppender"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="AppAppender" />
</root>
```

Thank you [@erencan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892994/erencan). You question really helped me look closely what is really happening inside that method.

Changed is at follows, and it work fine. Should log4j to this question's tags!

```
<logger name="com.abc.aspects.LogControllerAspect" additivity="false">
    <priority value="debug"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="AppAppender"/>
</logger>
```